# Kubernetes Ingress - same path but with multiple ports possible?

Tags: java, angular, kubernetes

I have an Angular frontend that I need to communicate with 2 microservices via websocket, using the same path (`/socket.io`), but different ports.

I have defined this ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
  labels:
    name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.host }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.name }}-service
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      - path: /socket.io
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: spectrogram-ms-backend-service
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /socket.io
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: anomaly-detection-microservice-service
            port:
              number: 5000
```

This worked fine with just the `spectrogram-ms-backend-service` in place, but now with the addition of the second Websocket (for the `anomaly-detection-microservice`), but I feel like it's being overridden.

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two paths defined for `/socket.io` with different backend services. However, Ingress only matches the first path that satisfies the conditions. So, the connections would always be routed to the `spectrogram-ms-backend-service` at port `8080`.

You can modify the config to something like this:

```
paths:
- path: /socket.io/{service-name}
  pathType: Prefix
  backend:
    service:
      name: {{ service-name }}-service
      port:
        number: {{ service-name }}-port
```

This way, you can achieve dynamic routing.

Just adjust Angular also:
e.g.
`/socket.io/spectrogram` for the first service and `/socket.io/anomaly-detection` for the second one.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should work. I just need to change the context on my backend for the spectrogram to expect /socket.io/spectrogram, then I'll do the same for my backend for the anomaly

Comment: That seems like a good way to go.